# Uncaught ReferenceError : a39Q0000000CvnaIAC is not found - Java script

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

1). I am not able to understand why is this exception coming in JavaScript. I am doing like below -

```
// Service Side Code
Calculator__c Calculator= [Select id, name, (select id, 
fee_amount__c, cost_Amount__c, Type__c, from
Cost_Details__r) From Calculator__c p where id =: PId];
```

> var ids = {!Calculator.Cost_Details__r};
>
> alert(ids.length);*/

Here server returns `[a39Q0000000CvnaIAC, a39Q0000000Cx5OIAS, a39Q0000000CvnfIAC]` string which in am assigning into ids variable.

alert is not coming up and when i goto error console i get -`Uncaught ReferenceError : a39Q0000000CvnaIAC is not found` JavaScript Exception.

2) I am calling a Java Script remote Function like below -

```
        function getPlanDetails() { 
            var str = "";
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.Details.getPlansDetails}',
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {                     
                        for(var i=0; i<result.length ; i++){
                            str += result[i].id;
                            str += ", ";
                            str += result[i].Cost_Amount_f__c;
                        }
                        alert(str);
                    } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Alert is showing `"Undefined, 1000"` Why Id is not being displayed in alert if my server side function returning both ID and Cost_Amount_f__c?

Comment: Whats the returns type in your visualforce remoting function?Can you get us the Apex controller so that we can tell exact error

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
[a39Q0000000CvnaIAC, a39Q0000000Cx5OIAS, a39Q0000000CvnfIAC]
```

is not an array of strings, it's assuming they are objects which of course they are not (hence a39Q0000000CvnaIAC is not found error) . To be an array of strings, I think it would have to be

```
["a39Q0000000CvnaIAC", "a39Q0000000Cx5OIAS", "a39Q0000000CvnfIAC"]
```

As for your second point, since Javascript is case sensitive, could it be that the platform is changing the case of your returned list values from your selected id to Id and it isn't recognising id. Try changing:

```
str += result[i].id;
```

To:

```
str += result[i].Id;
```

Comment: Then how can i resolve this error? and Why id is not being displayed in second example? can you please explain

Comment: Can we see your server side code?

Comment: I have edited my question and added service side query

Comment: @PramodKumar i've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in following one

```
for(var i=0; i<result.length ; i++){
                        str += result[i].id;
                        str += ", ";
                        str += result[i].Cost_Amount_f__c;
                    }
                    alert(str);
```

instead of iterating and adding to string, we can use the following one

```
var str = JSON.stringify(result);
alert(str);
```

will return json string of the result